# How to make windows search search in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, search

Ever since I've install Windows 10 I'm having this annoying problem. Windows search (Winkey+S) is not finding most of the stuff. It can find certain things such as Control Panel, or an executable if I happen to know the exact name of the .exe file, but not always. It is not finding programs in program files or even on desktop.

Here is an example. Say, I want to search for GOG Galaxy. I enter it in windows search like this:
[image]

It yields nothing. Same as if I type GalaxyClient.exe which is the name of the executable. It does not find anything useful even if I click "Search my stuff":

[image]

Which is quite surprising, given that I have GOG Galaxy right here on my desktop:

[image]

I also made sure that both my desktop and program files where Gog Galaxy is located are part of windows search index:

[image]

Gog Galaxy is just an example. It does not work with most of programs either.

How do I make it work? Do I need a third party program for this?

Answer (score -1):

So this is a rather common problem actually. Look for PowerShell in the start menu (it's under accessories in the "All Apps" section). Launch that as administrator and type this in:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

It may spit out an error at the end, but that is normal(? I just ignored it and search worked after). Hope this helps!

Comment: That didn't work and left more than a few errors. The calculator 'calc' could not even be found. https://ghostbin.com/paste/y83rb